# Can't make navbar sticky with a blur filter without body content overlapping nav while scroll?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to make a sticky navbar that has a blur effect like https://headlessui.dev/react/menu (try scrolling to see the blur effect on the nav). It should look like:

[image: headless-ui nav blur]

Here's what my HTML looks like:

```html
<header class="sticky z-10 top-10">
  <nav class="backdrop-filter backdrop-blur flex items-center justify-center h-16 font-semibold text-sm after:absolute after:inset-x-0 after:w-full after:h-12 after:shadow-hr after:z-[-1] mt-12">
    <section class="h-full">
      <a class="flex items-center justify-center h-full pl-4" href="/"
        ><svg width="176" height="177" viewBox="0 0 176 177" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-4 h-4 fill-current dark:text-white -rotate-6"><path d="M56.576.872h4.352l20.224 70.144L51.712 177H.512L56.576.872zm57.6 144.896H71.424l10.752-39.424h20.48L72.448.872h46.848L175.36 177h-52.224l-8.96-31.232z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg><span class="text-lg sr-only">Home</span></a
      >
    </section>
    <section class="h-full">
      <ul class="flex items-center justify-center h-full">
        <li class="mx-4"><a class="text-lg font-bold text-gray-700/75 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-white/50 dark:hover:text-white" href="/essays">Essays</a></li>
        <li class="mx-4"><a class="text-lg font-bold text-gray-700/75 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-white/50 dark:hover:text-white" href="/tutorials">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li class="mx-4"><a class="text-lg font-bold text-gray-700/75 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-white/50 dark:hover:text-white" href="/snippets">Snippets</a></li>
        <li class="mx-4"><a class="text-lg font-bold text-gray-700/75 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-white/50 dark:hover:text-white" href="/tips">Tips</a></li>
        <li class="mx-4"><a class="text-lg font-bold text-gray-700/75 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-white/50 dark:hover:text-white" href="/feed.xml">RSS</a></li>
        <li class="mx-4"><a class="text-lg font-bold text-gray-700/75 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-white/50 dark:hover:text-white" href="/about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </nav>
</header>

<h1 class="text-5xl font-bold text-center font-serif mt-20">All Essays By Date</h1>
<h2 class="w-3/4 mx-auto mt-4 mb-8 text-lg font-semibold text-center text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 sm:w-2/4">Scroll down to browse all of my essays by date and title. Essays are listed in reverse chronological order with my newest essay at the top and my oldest essay at the bottom.</h2>

<main class="prose block mx-auto">
  <p>Have you ever visited a website and been completely in awe of the elegance and simplicity of its design? For me, that website is <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://stripe.com/">Stripe</a>. Stripe is a company that allows people and businesses to accept payments online and in mobile apps. That doesn't sound like a company that would have an exquisite website design, but look at how Stripe describes themselves on their about page.</p>
  <blockquote>
    <p>"We think that building an internet business is a problem rooted in code and design, not finance."</p>
  </blockquote>
  <p>Rather than making design an afterthought, it's treated as a first-class citizen at Stripe. You can almost feel the hours of work spent iterating over designs and making minor tweaks when viewing the website's pages. In this article, I'm going to break down how Stripe creates these beautiful designs and give some tips and tricks to web designers and developers alike.</p>
  <h3 id="the-design">
    <a href="#the-design" class="anchor"><span class="icon icon-link"></span></a>The Design
  </h3>
  <div style="display: inline-block; max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px;">
    <div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: block; max-width: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Pictured above is the design for Stripe's main landing page. At first glance, here's what really sticks out to me:</p>
  <ol>
    <li>Crisp typography</li>
    <li>Stunning color palette</li>
    <li>High-quality images</li>
    <li>Bold call-to-action buttons</li>
  </ol>
  <p>Let's start with the first observation: the font.</p>
  <h3 id="typography">
    <a href="#typography" class="anchor"><span class="icon icon-link"></span></a>Typography
  </h3>
  <p>Stripe uses a font called <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.fontshop.com/families/camphor">Camphor</a>. It's a modern, uncluttered, sans serif font designed by Nick Job in 2010. It <em>really</em> shines here and looks great in a variety of weights.</p>
  <div style="display: inline-block; max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px;">
    <div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: block; max-width: 100%;">  </div>
  <p>Let's see how we can make our font as crisp and clear as possible. First, we'll define our font family to be Camphor along with some fallback fonts. <strong>Note:</strong> Camphor is not free and should be purchased if you're planning to use it in production. However, I did find a <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://gist.github.com/bdno86/d1f49b6f533df3f832b39d6cc3194303">gist containing the font</a> which you can mess around with.</p>
  <p>We can utilize the <code>text-rendering</code> CSS property to allow us to choose quality over speed, as well as some vendor specific properties to make our font sharper. <strong>Note:</strong> These should work for Chrome, Safari, and Firefox on Mac.</p>
  <pre class="language-css"><code class="language-css"><span class="token selector">body</span> <span class="token punctuation">{</span>
  <span class="token property">font-family</span><span class="token punctuation">:</span> Camphor<span class="token punctuation">,</span> Open Sans<span class="token punctuation">,</span> Segoe UI<span class="token punctuation">,</span> sans-serif<span class="token punctuation">;</span>
  <span class="token property">text-rendering</span><span class="token punctuation">:</span> optimizeLegibility<span class="token punctuation">;</span>
  <span class="token property">-webkit-font-smoothing</span><span class="token punctuation">:</span> antialiased<span class="token punctuation">;</span>
  <span class="token property">-moz-osx-font-smoothing</span><span class="token punctuation">:</span> grayscale<span class="token punctuation">;</span>
<span class="token punctuation">}</span>
</code></pre>
  <h3 id="example">
    <a href="#example" class="anchor"><span class="icon icon-link"></span></a>Example
  </h3>
  <p>In this example, I apply <code>-webkit-font-smoothing</code> followed by <code>text-rendering</code>.</p>
</main>
```

The relevant part is the `nav` part only. The rest of the boilerplate is to add content so it enables scroll.

I have created a [Tailwind Play reproduction](https://play.tailwindcss.com/WDz580IHV0).

Basically, I want to scroll with a sticky nav wihout overlapping content. How can I achieve that effect?

I added `backdrop-filter backdrop-blur` to `nav` to add the blur effect but the content scrolls above `nav` as my `height` probably isn't enough.

I added some `height` to the `header` & bunch of other properties like:

```css
height: 92px;
background: darkred;
position: relative;
top: 0;
```

But it isn't going to the `top` completely. I think I need to add a plain ol' `div` with a background color that is similar to `body` but I am confused where I should put it? Or it should be on the `header`?

I want the nav to be prominent basically with content scrolling below it if it makes sense. How do I do it?

Comment: its not a `blur` effect. The background-color is just `semi-transparent` which you can achieve by using a `RGBA` value as color.

Comment: @tacoshy yes, I noticed that it has `opacity: 0.5` but I have used `backdrop-filter backdrop-blur` class & it gives me the same effect. **what I am unable to achieve is taking the nav to the top with the same background?** I had a thought while writing this & i managed to get it right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make it sticky with content going under getting blurred using few tricks:

1. Changed `margin` to `padding` so `mt-12` becomes `pt-12`
2. Added `pb-10`
3. Changed `backdrop-filter backdrop-blur` from `nav` to `header`

This is the code that has changed:

```html
<header
  className="sticky top-0 z-10 pt-12 pb-10 backdrop-filter backdrop-blur
                   dark:bg-primary dark:text-white"
>
  <nav
    className="flex items-center justify-center h-16 font-semibold text-sm
       after:absolute after:inset-x-0 after:w-full after:h-12 after:shadow-hr after:z-[-1]"
  ></nav>
</header>
```